# Copying a bitmap from an Excel cell's comment to a Word document using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I wrote a macro to generate a questionnaire Word document from an Excel file.
The excel row looks like this (the image is inside the cell's comment):

[image: excel db]

I want the word Document to look like this:

[image: word result]

So far I managed to create the question, but without the picture using this code:

```
... open app and document and get the relevant styles...

With wSelection
    .Style = Question
    .TypeText vbCrLf

    .Style = QuestionBody
    .TypeText Range("A" & row).Value & vbCrLf


    'Here I need to copy the bitmap
    'How?


    .Style = Answer
    For Col = Asc("B") To Asc("E")
        answerOption = Range(Chr(Col) & row).Value
        .TypeText answerOption & vbCrLf
    Next Col

    .Style = wDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
End With
```

I cannot find how to copy the bitmap in the comment to the word document.
I tried to use:

```
Range("A" & row).Comment.Shape.CopyPicture
.PasteSpecial datatype:=wdPasteBitmap
'or just .Paste
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on HOW it "didn't work". Did you get an error? Did nothing copy? Or is something on the Clipboard, but pasting in Word is causing a problem?

Comment: @CindyMeister Nothing happened. The CopyPicture and PasteSpecial commands did not throw any error, but the bitmap did not appear in the word document.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Range("A" & row).Comment.Shape.CopyPicture.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
With wSelection
    .PasteSpecial datatype:=wdPasteBitmap
    ...
End With
```

Comment: It produces the same result as without `xlScreen, xlBitmap` , meaning, no bitmap is copied, no error is thrown (of course I assumed `CopyPicture` dup is just a typo in your answer)